# On ASP.NET ListView with LinqDataSource, display the data when the search button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listview, linqdatasource

I have a ListView setup with LinqDataSource and a button that triggers search function. To avoid display data on page_load, I set ListView's DataSourceID in the Click event of the search button, bind it and set result data in LinqDataSource's Selecting event. It works as I expected but It does't look pretty to set DataSourceId in the button Click event every time the search button is clicked. How can I do this in a better and clearer way?

ASPX code:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server"
    ContextTypeName="WebApplication1.DataClasses1DataContext" EntityTypeName=""
    TableName="Persons" onselecting="LinqDataSource1_Selecting">
</asp:LinqDataSource>

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" >...</asp:ListView>

<asp:Button ID="Search" Text="Search" runat="server" Click="Search_Clicked"/>
```

ASPX.CS code:

```
protected void Search_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView1.DataSourceID = LinqDataSource1.ID;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}

protected void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    //Search Criteria from CheckBoxList and TextBox applied here.
    DataClasses1DataContext data = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var query = from result in data.Persons
                where result.ID > 2
                select result;
    e.Result = query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't see anything wrong with your approach, however, if you don't like it, an alternate approach would be to just statically set the `DataSourceID` in your `ListView` markup as usual, but set `Visible="False"`, and only make it visible once the button has been clicked.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, womp.

I thought about it too but the problem doing that is when it binds, it still retrieves data from DB on page load without any search criteria. I just wondered if there's any way to bind datasource to listview and not retrieve data until specifically tell it to do so.